# Magento migrate 1.9.3.1 to Magento 2.3.4 (multistore): Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified key: 'NULL'

Tags: theme, migration, luma-theme

I've get a problem when try get any page.

My process migration is regular.

Only different I not' install template in Magento 2. I like use for testing Luma

After migrate settings and migrate data without errors (only a problem with short url) get a problem with theme.

https://www.tiendafetichista.ovh/ Show site with somre problem but show.
https://www.tiendafetichista.ovh/esenciales/ Click on any menu ad I get error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified key: 'NULL'

Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified key: 'NULL'
```

I go to

> **dashboard > Content > Design Configuration and all store has "-- No Theme --"**
>
> **I put theme name "Magento Luma" for store, and after I clean caches.**

But not work....

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean cache and update module/settings by shell?

Ex. run this on shell:

```
rm -rf var/* ; rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*; rm -rf generated/code/*; php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento indexer:reindex; php bin/magento cache:clean; php bin/magento cache:flush; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ;
```

Comment: Yes... this not work.

Answer (score 0):

First you backup the your database and Try this

I found `themename` in database table **design_change** and delete the table content.

More Information refer this link :-

**[Error after Migration: Unable to load theme by specified key (Magento 2)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112764/error-after-migration-unable-to-load-theme-by-specified-key-magento-2)**

Comment: There're nothing in this table. Is empty --> st1_design_change

Comment: Already my design_change empty, still theme not loading in frondend, how to solve the issue?

Comment: i think answer is right --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112807/85907